# Understanding encoding in a large retail dataset

Tags: data-mining

According to the dataset [specification](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/retail.pdf) each line of the [text file](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/retail.dat.gz) is to represent an individual receipt. Each column (6 in total) represents: date, receipt no, item no, quantity, price and customer no.

The trouble is that the number of column entries varies considerably -- from 1 to 30; the numbers are nothing like e.g. the date format.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 
33 34 35 
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 
38 39 47 48 
38 39 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 
32 41 59 60 61 62 
3 39 48 
63 64 65 66 67 68
```

Since this is data used in published research, I doubt it is corrupted; more likely encoded in some standard I am not aware of. How does one interpret the meaning of columns?

Comment: There is very little we will be able to suggest here. The only thing really is to go where you got the data and look for an explanation or someone to contact and ask.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I went through the specification (http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/retail.pdf); the dataset also appears in multiple sources (in the same format) with no additional remarks, which would imply it is, for lack of a better word, "self-evident".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite obviously, something is broken here. [The data](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/retail.dat) and [the description](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/retail.pdf) do not match *at all*.

The data could conceivably be basket data with anonymized items. The first line could be one basket containing 30 items, which were anonymized and coded as 0-29. The second line could be another basket, with three different items, coded 30-32. And so forth. Item 38 is contained in baskets (rows) 4, 5 and 6.

However, there is *nothing whatsoever* that corresponds to the following paragraph in the description:

> Each record in the data set contains information about the date of
>   purchase (variable ’date’), the receipt number (variable ’receipt
>   nr’), the article number (variable ’article nr’), the number of items
>   purchased (variable ’amount’), the article price in Belgian Francs
>   (variable ’price’ with 1 Euro = 40.3399 BEF) and the customer number
>   (variable ’customer nr’).

It appears possible that some files were corrupted or copied on top of each other at some point. I suggest that you contact the maintainer of the data, whose email address you find in the data description.

Comment: Tried emailing the author, but the email bounced back. Are there any alternative good open retail datasets, that could potentially be used for educational purposes (retail data-mining).

Comment: Sounds like you should start some *serious* sleuthing. Contact the maintainer of the original data site (http://fimi.ua.ac.be/). Look for recent coauthors of the author and ask nicely whether they have contact info or could at least forward your inquiry. And so on. No, I am not aware of any open retail data, and I have been working for retail for almost a decade. For the most part, retailers are *utterly paranoid* about their data. I could tell you stories you wouldn't believe (but I would have to kill you afterwards).

Comment: Lovely. Perhaps this is the reason this data is not decipherable :D